how to properly import the python module?
Hi I am new to python and learning the import module.
I have import one object that is needed into this file:
project/third_party/intel/backend/compiler.py
from this file:
project/python/chimera/runtime/driver.py
How should I write the import statement?
There is another file:
project/python/chimera/compiler/compiler.py
that need to import the same object in this way:
from ..runtime.driver import driver.
I just could understand how to use .. and how to write my import statement.
Thanks!

Are the modules part of the same project? If not, is compiler.py installed somehow?

Show your work. We can help you fix your code.

If the files are from the same project you can import like this:
from <folder.file_name> import <class>

For an example, this folder structure

Project

Src

file.py


Imgs
main.py



The file.py has this content:
class to_test():
   def __init__():
      print('something')

And I wanna use it in main.py, then at main.py I do this:
from Src.file import to_test

